# Would it be a good idea to drop out of my Bachelor's program and look for scholarships to restart abroad?

Tags: academic-life

Currently, I study BA in Mathematics, and because of some problems related to the environment I found myself in, I cannot complete my studies in this place.
I studied most of the courses, except Topology, Fields & Rings, Real Analysis 2, Numerical Analysis, and some elective courses. In general the education level here is not that good, so I have decided to drop it and start again in another (good) place.

But, if I do this, I don't know if it will be good for me and for my journey. I plan to move from the Middle East either to Europe or the USA, to study there and start the bachelor's again. Moreover, I'm 23 years old now. and I don't know if my age will cause a problem.

Any advice?

Comment: Not sure, but this might be off-topic since it is related to undergraduate admissions.

Comment: It is unlikely that you would need to "start over", but the US system is probably very different from what you are used to with many required courses outside maths.

Comment: There are very few scholarships for international students at the undergraduate level in the United States.  Most foreign undergraduates in the US are supported by their relatively wealthy parents.  The situation is very different for MS and PhD degrees.

Comment: How much longer before you could finish the degree? One year? 2 years?

Comment: @mkennedy I think I need two year.

Answer (score 2):

Different countries in Europe have a different opinion on what constitutes "old" for a student. There are countries where 23 would still be quite young.

You may want to have a look into whether programmes in the EU or USA would allow you to transfer (part of) the credits for courses you already passed. Some programs will, some programs won't. If you find a program that allows this, it might make your journey substantially smoother.

Comment: Yes, look for a program in several places to see what the real effect would be. Guessing about this is not a good idea. You may need to speak with some admissions people to learn what the outcome might be.